# Implementation of MYOB AccountRight API

Tags: myob

I need to entered invoices and purchases into live company file. Created account but when I logged in to `https://my.myob.com.au/bd/Pages/Home.aspx` URL I did not see any developer tab for register API.

Please help me to implement myob API.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You need to express your interest to access the cloud hosted companyfiles

http://developer.myob.com/contact/register-for-myobapi-access/

Answer (score 2):

1. you need to register your app via MYOB with your developer account.
2. you need to setup call back url within your application config page. It can be a localhost url
3. you need to install the offical sdk (c# or ruby) to your application.

from the local

a. init the sdk client with access key, secret key and call back url

b. redirect the customer to the myob auth page (the url can be auto generated from sdk)

c. after the auth operation, a code will be send to your callback url

d. use the code to init the myob sdk and get the list of company files

e. select a company file and get information you need